# SCIP: Getting lower bounds and upper bounds in various modes at a specific node

Tags: scip

I want to get lower bounds and upper bounds at a specific node of the branch-and-bound tree in various modes. It will help me compare the various emphasis settings.

For this (an example for lower bounds),

- I made a global copy of the MIP at that node obtaining a separate SCIP instance using `SCIPCopy()`
- Then set `separating/emphasis` as `aggressive`, `presolve` as False, and `limits/nodes` as 1
- `optimize` the model

This procedure does several iterations of simplex on a single node before exiting.

- Will this lower bound be similar to the lower bound obtained if the settings were set to `separating/emphasis/aggressive` just before the node was processed in the branch-and-bound tree? ( a similar doubt is for upper bounds by changing `heuristics/emphasis/aggressive` )
- Is there a function - `SCIPComputeLowerBound(setting=1)` for a `SCIP_NODE`. (similarly, for `SCIPComputeUpperBound(setting=1)`?
- If I decide to go with `aggressive` or `fast` in `separating`, how can I copy the results of the node back to the original SCIP's node? (and similarly for "heuristics" where I will need to update the original solution). *I can think of changing the settings to a desired level in the original SCIP tree, and let it solve with the changed settings, but this will require solving that node twice.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The lower bounds will probably not be the same, especially for separating. The reason is that many separators run longer during the root node than further down in the tree. Additionally separators and heuristics in SCIP have a `frequency` which means that they will not be called at every node. So it could be that at your current node no heuristics will be run, but if you create a new subscip and solve the root node there heuristics will run.

What should this function `SCIPcomputeLowerBound` do? Solve the whole node but not change anything? (that does not exist)

You can copy definitely copy a solution back over, e.g. look at `createNewSolution` in `heur_rens.c`. What would you want to copy over from the separation?

Comment: If I were to switch the emphasis from default to aggressive midway the solution process, will it reset all the counters for heuristics and separating?

Comment: I see that there are some algorithms in heuristics and separation which have a `freq=-1`. Are those the ones that are called at every node?  Specifically, what is the basis of these settings and how is it decided at each node which heuristics/separation to use?

Comment: What `counters` do you mean? The frequency settings and so on will be changed. `freq = -1` means disabled by default, every node would be `freq = 1`. Heuristics and separators are called in order of their priority. Additionally, heuristics have a timing, determining when they are called, e.g. after the lp was solved. Please make sure to also check the FAQ https://scip.zib.de/doc/html/FAQ.php since many of your questions (frequency for example) are already answered there.

Comment: Sorry, I confused frequency with quotas. What is meant by a `freq=10` on `mfc`? Does it mean that it will run the `mfc` heuristics 10 times on every node? My confusion is regarding how is the solver deciding which heuristics or separator to call on any node? Is there some `meta-heuristic` for that? Are these settings decided to make the solver compete with CPLEX?

Comment: Your question is completely answered by the documentation, so I will just leave a link to the relevant section https://scip.zib.de/doc/html/HEUR.php